# C# datatype coercion in static size

Tags: c#, coercion

So if I define a some constants

```
const byte MAX_SIZE = 100;
```

And then instantiate an integral array with the static size above

```
int[] myArr = new int[MAX_SIZE];
```

Is the static size explicit coercion or this perfectly acceptable.

Just curious as I'm not getting any warnings in VS Visual C# 2013, or is there a way so we can make the warnings more strict?

Comment: It's const so compiler replaces every MAX_SIZE with its value while compiling.

Comment: So no coercion exists then, byte->int

Comment: What exactly do you think is being coerced here?

Comment: I'm wondering if [(byte)100] is coerced to [(int)100] or not

Comment: Just curious as to how the static size actually works, my professor is very strict on implicit and explicit coercion. I know it for the most part except this how to actually works.

Comment: this is the `IL` for the const declaration `.field private static literal uint8 MAX_SIZE = uint8(100)`  so yes the compiler will convert the `(byte)100` to `(int)100`

Comment: thanks Mohamed understandable,

Answer (score 4):

Value will be *implicitly converted* to int. See c# specification.

> 7.6.10.4 Array creation expressions
>
> ...new   non-array-type   [   expression-list   ] ...
>
> Each expression in the expression list must be of type int, uint, long, or ulong, or implicitly convertible to one or more of these types.
>
> ... Following evaluation of each expression, an implicit conversion (§6.1) to one of the following types is performed: int, uint, long, ulong. The first type in this list for which an implicit conversion exists is chosen.